# counting cosecutive numbers in arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Problem H [Longest Natural Successors]
Two consecutive integers are natural successors if the second is the successor of the first in the sequence of natural numbers (1 and 2 are natural successors). Write a program that reads a number N followed by N integers, and then prints the length of the longest sequence of consecutive natural successors. Example:

Input
7 2 3 5 6 7 9 10    Output  3
here is my code so far can anyone help me plz

```
   import java.util.Scanner;


   public class Conse {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
     int x=scan.nextInt();
     int[] array= new int[x];
     for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
         array[i]=scan.nextInt();
     System.out.println(array(array));


     }
   public static int array(int[] array){
    int count=0,temp=0;
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        count=0;
        for(int j=i,k=i+1;j<array.length-1;j++,k++)
            if(array[j]-array[k]==1)
                count++;
            else{if(temp<count)
                temp=count;
            break;}
        }
    return temp+1;
    }

   }
```

Comment: and does your code work? if not, what does not work?

Comment: @cello why does it keep reading integers in case if no integers in array are consecutive?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ArrayList<Integer> outList = new ArrayList<Integer>()
int lastNum = array[0];
for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++;)
    if((lastNum + 1) == array[i])
        outList.add(array[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the line `i=counter;` should be `i += counter`. otherwise, you're always resetting the loop-counter `i` to zero, and so it never progresses.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the inner for loop, as this can be done with one single scan through the array:

```
public static int consecutive(int[]array) {
    int tempCounter = 1; //there will always be a count of one
    int longestCounter = 1; //always be a count of one
    int prevCell = array[0];
    for(int i=1;i<array.length;i++) {
        if( array[i] == (prevCell + 1)) {
           tempCounter++; //consecutive count increases
        } else {
           tempCount =1; //reset to 1
        }
        if(tempCounter > longestCounter) {
           longestCounter = tempCounter; //update longest Counter
        }
        prevCell = array[i];
    }
    return longestCounter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int sequenceStart = 0;
int sequenceLength = 0;
int longestSequenceLength = 0;
for (int item: array) {
    if (item == sequenceStart + sequenceLength) {
        sequenceLength++;
    } else {
        sequenceStart = item;
        sequenceLength = 1;
    }
    longestSequenceLength = Math.max(longestSequenceLength, sequenceLength);
}
```